# Using vector affine transformation in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, affine-transformation

I'm trying to use the QGIS plugin `vector affine transformation` to translate a shapefile with wrong coordinates using the right coordinates of another shapefile. 
It looks like this[image]

I read other answers to this problem but still my transformation does not work.
I take the coordinates of 3 points of the original shapefile:

```
396379.157,4992456.237
396434.636,4992428.498
396494.740,4992398.908
```

I take the coordinates of the same 3 points of the target shapefile:

```
396373.609,4992445.141
396431.169,4992416.939
396492.312,4992386.888
```

Then from online solver I get parameters to include into the transformation matrix:

```
U = -0.276
V = -2.628
W = 13625340.309
X = 19.103
Y = -197.695
Z = 380203686.883
```

or using another solver:

```
q = -0.279
r = -2.634
s = 13657434.35
t = 48.227
u = 158.434
v = 177246147.891
```

then I complete the QGIS transformation matrix

```
 -0.279 -2.634 13657434.35
48.227 158.434 177246147.891
```

But what happens is not a translation and it looks like this
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Is it because my transformation does not include rotation?

Ideas about how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
I understood that what I need is just a translation, I don't need to rescale or rotate the shapefile. Therefore, instead of using the whole matrix of the affine transformation plugin (which continues to give incorrect results) I just took the coordinates of one point in the original (wrong) shapefile, (396460.52513,4992655.01317) then I took the coordinates for the same point in the target shapefile (396374.45124,4992446.61507) and i calculated the difference (x:-86,07389 y: -208,3981). I then used the transformation matrix of Affine Transformation filling 1 0 and the last column  with my "difference of coordinates":
1 0 -86,07389
0 1 -208,3981
And it works!